# Restaurant daily menu - days to show

Tags: lists, structure, collapsible-panels

I'm currently working on a minor redesign for a restaurant/pub website. This restaurant serves a daily menu, which means that it changes for every day.

On their current website, the menu is always shown for the entire current week. The items are in a pretty big font, so the user has to scroll all the way down to see what they can get on friday for example, while at the top, they see what they could get on monday, which might no longer be relevant.

My first idea was to collapse past days, leaving upcoming days expanded by default and highlighting the current day.

As I started writing the code, I though I could completely remove past days, and only show the current day (or one previous day at most) and upcoming, maybe 5 or so, days.

That way, only the relevant information would be shown, however, I'm afraid this could confuse some users (I, for example, don't recall ever seeing a menu structured like this).

Should I rather stick to the "entire current week (with collapsed past days)"?

Comment: I usually expect the Daily Menu to be just today's menu.

Comment: Is this a regular cycling menu? E.g. Monday is always Hot Wings, Tuesday is Burgers etc. Or does the menu changes day to day? That might affect how it should be displayed.

Comment: @nightning We can say it changes day to day. Some items repeat after a month or so, but in a random fashion, e.g. Monday of week 46 is Hot Wings, then we have Hot Wings again on Tuesday, week 50, and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would be important to understand what motivates people to go to the website. Based on my past experience it is mostly for address, hours, phone number and reservations. Menus are accessed, but more like a sample of what **could** be available.

First, does the pub take reservations for the restaurant? If so, how far in advance do people book?

Also, you can test what people are actually interested in by tracking in something like Google Analytics to see whether they actually click on future menus or not.

Finally, you can always just go into the restaurant and run a quick survey of people that are there. Did they check the website? If so, why? If so, when?

Of course, all of this may be overkill for what you are designing. Why not just have a sub menu that has the days of the week?